# Examples of group homomorphisms with isomorphic but not equal images

Tags: group-theory

This may be a poor question. I am having trouble thinking of a pair of group homomorphisms: $\varphi, \Psi: G \rightarrow H$ between groups where $\varphi(G) \neq \Psi(G)$ but $\varphi(G) \cong \Psi(G)$. What were some examples of this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $G=H=\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z \times \cdots$, an infinite number of factors.

Take $\varphi=$ id and $\Phi=$ shift: $\Phi(x_1,x_2,\dots)=(0,x_1,x_2,\dots)$.

For an example with finite groups, take $G=S_n$, $H=S_m$, with $m>n$, $\varphi=$ inclusion, $\Phi $ obtained by renumbering $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ to $\{1+k,\dots,n+k\}$, for $k=1,\dots,m-n$. Each $k$ gives one $\Phi$.

Not sure whether $n!$ and $m!$ count as small order, though...

Comment: Great, I just read your edit.

Answer (score 3):

This is a minimal counterexample:

$G = \mathbb{Z}_2$, $H = \mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2$ with $\phi(g) = (g,0)$ and $\psi(g) = (0,g)$.

Comment: Great, this is what I was looking for. Sorry if this question was obvious.